# How to search CSS / JavaScript files with Google?

Tags: google-search

Is there a way to find CSS / JavaScript files that contain certain keywords:

- in the title ?
- in the code ?

Comment: How about using `filetype:css` and `filetype:js` in the query?

Comment: It works! Post an answer that I give you points.

Comment: Just to add, `filetype:css` searches URLs that have the extension ".css", and likewise for ".js". It doesn't search files that have the associated mime types. So the pages returned in a `filetype:css` search are all forward facing pages in the visible content of the website, they aren't the external CSS files that are linked to from the HTML document.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the title"?

Comment: @w3d I think the OP means “in the name of the file.”

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `filetype:` search operator.

- `filetype:css`
- `filetype:js`

However,

> When you use the `filetype:` operator in a Google search (for example, `filetype:xml galway`), Google searches for files with the .xml extension, **not** for files of file type XML.
>
> Not all URLs or pages have the .html file extension. Some pages (like http://www.google.com) have no extension at all, and some have an extension that doesn't match their file type. Limiting your search to a specific file type will return pages with that file extension, and may return fewer relevant results.

[Source](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35287).

Comment: I don't think this is supported anymore.